# Sync Outlook mails with iPad 2 via iTunes or any without Internet connection?

Tags: data-synchronization, ms-office, ipad

I haven't found any way for syncing my Outlook mails via iTunes with USB cable to my iPad 2. Do you know any method or program for syncing your mails to read them later on the iPad without an Internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no ways, and I found this for u. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/mac-outlook-help/some-outlook-items-aren-t-synchronizing-with-other-mac-applications-HA102928388.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102928396

Answer (score 0):

The best way (a bit difficult) I have found is that exporting inbox as .pst file and then using .pst reader program on ipad like [Pst Mail for iPad](http://www.arrowbit.com/tips-pstmail-ipad) .

with Pst Mail Transferring Outlook pst files to your iPad:

1. Open iTunes and select your iPad device
2. On the top bar, select the "Apps" tab
3. Scroll down to File Sharing and select Pst Mail
4. Click "add" and upload as many pst files as you wish

i hope this can help people who has the same problem.